# How to style a component in nextjs

Tags: css, sass, next.js, styling

There doesn't seem to an answer for this. I have components and I don't know how to style then. I created a component.module.css and then tried importing and it just throws an error. Is there a better way ?

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: Please tell more about error being thrown. Ideally it should be a file (component.module.css). And then " import styles from './component.module.css'. Also path depends where your modular css is. refer this https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css

Comment: i've tried this, it just says import module not resolved. it can't seem to pick it up. The directory is as follows pages/components/component. This is in it _app.js import '../styles/Home.module.scss'